# Extract properties of a list that is nested inside another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list within another list from which I would like to extract all the properties but cannot figure out a way to do so.
The `CartItem` class is the class in question which is nested inside the `Order` class as `final List<CartItem> products`
I would be specifically needing the imageUrl and title properties but would like a way to iterate through all of it.
I'm pretty new to Dart and Flutter.

```
CartItem

class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final double price;
  final double quantity;
  final String imageUrl;
  
  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.imageUrl
  });
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};
  
  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }
```

And here is the `Order` Class

```
class Order {
  final String id;
  final double amount;
  final List<CartItem> products; //This is the nested list out of which I need the CartItem properties extraced
  final DateTime date;

  Order({
    required this.id,
    required this.amount,
    required this.products,
    required this.date
});
}

class OrderItem with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Order> _order = [];

  List<Order> get orders {
    return[..._order];
  }
```

The widget that I'm trying to implement this is `ManageOrderScreen` the code for which is below.

```
class ManageOrderScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final orderProvider = Provider.of<OrderItem>(context).orders;
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Manage Orders"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ManageOrderWidget(orderProvider[index]),
        itemCount: orderProvider.length
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ManageOrderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Order order;

  ManageOrderWidget(this.order);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Card(
        elevation: 5,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              order.products.map((e) => {
                'imageUrl' : e.imageUrl
              }).toList()
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            order.products.map((e) => {'title' : e.title}).toList()
          ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you're passing a list instead of a string to the ``NetworkImage()`` and ``Text()`` widget.

Comment: secondly, you can access the first image from the order as: ``order.products[0].imageUrl`` and title as:  ``order.products[0].title``.

Comment: to show all the images and title, you need to wrap the list of images and titles with a typical ``listview``

Comment: If you're using flutter always include some of the widget code in the initial question this will save time and effort of both ends.  The initial question came across as a general programming question but only now with the update do we know the specific's and can give you a working solution. See [How to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
class ManageOrderScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final orderProvider = Provider.of<OrderItem>(context).orders;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Manage Orders"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ManageOrderWidget(orderProvider[index]),
        itemCount: orderProvider.length
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ManageOrderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Order order;

  ManageOrderWidget(this.order);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
    return ListView.builder(
         physics:ClampingScrollPhysics(), 
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: order.products.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          final CartItem _item = order.products[index];
          return Card(
            elevation: 5,
             shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
             ), 
            child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_item.imageUrl),
          ),
          title: Text(_item.title),
      )
    );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Since the focus of this question is on iterating the list and accessing the properties of the `Order` class I've focused on that, you'll can change the properties as needed to get the desired output.

Comment: I now get an error saying The argument type 'List<Map<String, String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. I tried using the .toString() method but that doesn't show the picture except for the primary color in the background and the text I see on the emulator looks like ({title : Red Shirt}). I have added the widget that I'm trying to implement this on above.

Comment: Ah Well...that's a simple fix. I'll update the answer to include the widget, since you've updated the question.